# Moving a sprite in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I have an app that has a server that keeps a position of a ball and sends it 60 times per second to clients.

Based on that input I'm updating Phaser sprite x,y coordinates and velocity, and I expected to have a smooth transition, but what I got is jittery movement.

I tried using `Sprite.moveToXY`, but then I get even stranger behavior, so is there a correct/good way of moving/updating sprite position

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is network jitter - network packets are delivered to your app with varying time intervals.

What you need to do is to [interpolate your sprite's position](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/entity-interpolation.html) to the last received server position. Using velocity from the server probably unnecessary in your case.

Oh, and sending network packets less often than 60 FPS may also help, for example try 20 FPS.